# R mutate() function when used to subtract two dates automatically results the difference in seconds. How do I show minutes or minutes and seconds?

Tags: r, datetime

Using the following mutate function results the new column "ride_length" to show the difference of the two dates in seconds:

```
combined_ctd %>% 
  mutate(cyclist_trip_data_all, ride_length = ended_at-started_at)
```

How do I make it show minutes and seconds in a single column?

Comment: You can probably use `?difftime` to customize the units of the result, depending on the class of the input columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas `combined_ctd %>%  mutate(cyclist_trip_data_all, ride_length = difftime(ended_at,started_at,units='mins'))` I tried this but it's still calculating seconds for some reason...

Comment: What class are you input columns? Could you share a few rows of data reproducibly? `dput()` is the nicest way to share copy/pasteable data including class information, something like `dput(combined_ctd[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows. Deselect irrelevant columns if you have many columns.

Comment: Please, share sample data here for reproducibility as @GregorThomas mentioned (a few rows of the data, can be hypothetical but of the same format). That way we can reproduce and provide answers that are guaranteed to work.